# Loop Regression Lm and replace NAs

Tags: loops, replace, lm

I have a dataset of length and heights for shells, however in some years height was not recorded. I am trying to use a linear regression of the years of data where both height and length was recorded in order to generate heights for the years with NAs.
On top of this I want it to do this regression for each of my Assessment areas.

So far this is what I have;

```
 for(a in unique(all_data$Assessment_area)) { 
 r1 <- lm(Height_t2~Length_t2,data=all_data[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)&all_data$Assessment_area==a,]) #Regression model for all shells with L&H
 print(a)
 print(r1)
 }
```

which gives me the output that I need for each assessment area (Which I am then inserting into the code below i.e. 0.8871 and 0.5143 but at the moment one by one).
The next bit of my code is creates a new column as follows, where I was typing in each time the generated values. Is there a way of incorporating these lines into the previous loop?

```
 all_data$Height_r1 <- all_data$Length_t2*0.8871+0.5143 #Apply regression relationship to new column
 all_data$Height_r1[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)] <-all_data$Height_t2[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)] #Add original heights
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: What are 08871 and 0.5143? Is that the result of the lm in the previous step?

Comment: Yes but there are 5 assessment areas so there are 5 sets of results, so i also need to specify to only replace height values for each assessment area using the calculated regression for that area. Previously when I have used this code I have just used one single regression equation for all of the shells but I think it would be more accurate to have regional/assessment_area scale regressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the result of a linear regression using the $ operator on the summary function.  In this case, you would do

```
r1coefs <- summary(r1)$coefficients
intercept <- r1coeffs[1]
slope <- r1coeffs[2]
```

You can then incorporate these into your loop as follows:

```
for(a in unique(all_data$Assessment_area))

{ r1 <- lm(Height_t2~Length_t2,data=all_data[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)&all_data$Assessment_area==a,]) #Regression model for all shells with L&H
print(a)
print(r1)
#access the linear regression coefficients and store them        
r1coefs <- summary(r1)$coefficients
intercept <- r1coeffs[1]
slope <- r1coeffs[2]

#use the stored regression coefficients on the new data
all_data$Height_r1 <- all_data$Length_t2*slope+intercept #Apply regression relationship to new column
all_data$Height_r1[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)] <-all_data$Height_t2[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)] #Add original heights  
}
```

Comment: Thank you bsg, that code runs fine but when I check the output some of them are off a bit. Only one of 5 assessment areas heights are as I can generate them on a calculator. Many are not quite right for example. For Assessment area A the printed out Slope is 0.8877 and Intercept 0.8175 so for a length of 44*0.8877+0.8175 I get 39.8763 but r is generating 39.3548 which is enough difference for some heights to round to the wrong mm. I can't think why this might be the case?

Comment: Ah It looks like it is only using one equation for them all still which is why one assessment area is as it should be and the others are not. There must be something missing from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :) Just needed some extra bits to specify Assessment_area when using the stored regressions on the data ;

```
 for(a in unique(all_data$Assessment_area)) {
 r1 <- lm(Height_t2~Length_t2,data=all_data[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)    &all_data$Assessment_area==a,]) 
#Regression model for all shells with L&H
 print(a)
 print(r1)
 #access the linear regression coefficients and store them        
 r1coeffs <- summary(r1)$coefficients
  intercept <- r1coeffs[1]
 slope <- r1coeffs[2]

   #use the stored regression coefficients on the new data

   all_data[all_data$Assessment_area==a,"Height_r1"] <- all_data   [all_data$Assessment_area==a,"Length_t2"]*slope+intercept #Apply regression relationship to new column

}

 #Add original heights         
all_data$Height_r1[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)] <-all_data$Height_t2[!is.na(all_data$Height_t2)]
```